# Which local repository contains my code "origin/develop" or "develop"

Tags: git

Using git-flow and VSTS, when I "clone" from the browser to "develop" does that update my local: "origin/develop" or "develop" branch? I appear to be having inconsistent results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`origin/develop` is the **remote tracking** branch. It represents the state of the `develop` branch on the upstream repository.

When you fetch, it goes into `origin/develop`. When you pull, it fetches into `origin/develop`, then merges `origin/develop` into `develop`. You should be working in `develop`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I understand what you're saying, but you haven't addressed my question directly. Am I to infer that the process of cloning *"should" put the latest code into my local "develop" branch then, or does that cloning process create a copy onto "origin/develop"?

Comment: The process of cloning creates a copy of the repository and only happens once, when you initially synchronize the repo. At the time of cloning, develop and origin/develop will be exactly the same (i.e. they will both point to the same commit). After that, it works exactly as I described: fetching updates the contents of origin/develop. Whether it updates the develop branch or not depends on whether you did a fetch, or a pull (with a pull representing two distinct operations, fetch+merge).

Comment: On that note, do you have a specific problem that you're encountering and trying to solve? Because the overall question is a bit strange, and some of the details you're mentioning aren't relevant to the question (such as using git-flow).

Comment: Yes, I was getting a mix of old and new code b/c I didn't understand (wasn't trained) on how this is supposed to work. Thank you! You ROCK sir!

Answer (score 0):

For one short version, see [Daniel Mann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61599781/1256452).  I'm going to *guess* what your real question is:

> why, sometimes, does `git merge` (or `git pull`) leave me "one ahead", and sometimes not?

The TL;DR is: because `git merge` (or the `git merge` that `git pull` runs) can do one of two different things.

#### Background (long)

There are several things to realize when working with Git, that are different from working with centralized version control systems.  The number one most important thing is this: **There is more than one repository.**  But there isn't (normally anyway) more than one *local* repository.  One of the repositories is *yours* and is local, and one or more are someone else's, and not local.  So:

> Which local repository contains my code ...

The literal answer to this question is *your (single) local repository*.  This isn't the right question!

You might want instead to ask which (local) branch is yours, but that's the wrong question again: In Git, *all **branch names*** are local.  The trick here is that the name `origin/develop` isn't a *branch name*.  It is, instead, a *remote-tracking name* (or what Git calls a *remote-tracking branch name*—I think this slightly less confusing if we just drop the word *branch*, which through overuse, has already become meaningless by this point).

To try to keep this short, I'll skip over a lot of details and imprecision here:

- Git isn't really about branches after all.  Git is all about *commits*.  That's the unit of storage you'll work with.
- Each commit has a unique hash ID.  In effect, this is the "true name" of the commit.  These hash IDs are *globally* unique, across every Git repository.  (This is why they have to be so big and ugly, so that no Git anywhere ever accidentally re-uses the same hash ID as any other Git anywhere.)
- Gits share commits with each other by these hash IDs.  Any Git repository can tell if it has a commit yet, because the hash ID is globally unique.  Either you do have that hash ID, in which case you do have the commit, or you don't, so you don't.
- Each commit stores a snapshot of all of your files, as its data, plus some metadata, such as who made the commit, when, and so on.  One of the metadata items is for Git itself and it is a list of hash IDs of *previous* commits.  Usually there is just one entry here: the previous or *parent* commit for this ordinary, non-merge commit.

So given some chain of commits, the *last* commit is the only one we can't find by using a later commit and working backwards:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

If `H` is the *last* commit, we can use it to find `G`, which we can use to find `F`, and so on.  (The letters here stand in for the actual hash IDs, which are random-looking and too hard for humans to work with.)

These backwards-looking chains of commits are, or can be, called branches.  But branch *names* like `master` and `develop` can also be called branches.  Remote-tracking names can be called branches as well.  See [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)

A *branch name* like `master` or `develop` simply holds the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  To add a new commit, your Git will write out the new commit, pointing backwards to the previously-last commit, and then write the new commit's hash ID into your branch name.

Your branch names are all *yours*.  Your `develop` is solely *yours*.  Your Git will update it as you add new commits.  Your Git can update your branch name with `git merge`, too, and other commands.

The other Git repository you're using has a URL.  That URL is stored under a *name*, which Git calls a *remote*.  The standard first remote name is always `origin`, so `origin` is the *remote*.  The `git clone` command sets this up for you automatically, which is why `origin` is the standard first remote.

That other Git has its own branch names.  (There's no need for you and them to use the *same* names, but you probably would like to use the same names just for your own sanity.)  They'll have commits added to *their* `develop`, from time to time.

Your Git will call up their Git, using the URL stored under the name `origin`.  Their Git will then hand over any new commits they have that you don't, and now you'll have them.  Your Git will now update your `origin/develop` to remember the hash ID *they* had stored under *their* branch name `develop`.  Your `origin/develop` is a *remote-tracking name*, not a branch name.

There's one other tricky bit here.  When you run your initial `git clone`, your Git:

- creates a new, empty repository (no commits, no branches, nothing);
- sets up the name `origin` to hold the URL;
- uses `git fetch` to get all their commits and branch names, renaming all their branch name to your remote-tracking names: this is where your initial `origin/master` and `origin/develop` come from; and
- last, runs `git checkout`.  This *creates new branch*, because at the moment you have no branches at all.

Let's take a look at what your repository might look like, in part, right after a `git clone <url>`.  Let's suppose that *their* Git recommends that your `git clone` do a `git checkout master` as its last step.  You might now have this

```
...--o--E   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
         \
          F--G--H   <-- origin/develop
```

Your Git just *created* your `master` (and attached `HEAD` to it), to point to commit `E`, some commit you got in the initial fetch.  Their `master`, in their repository, names commit `E`, so your new `master` also names commit `E`.

Your Git *renamed* all their branch names to make your `origin/*` remote-tracking names.  So your `origin/master` points to commit `E`, and your `origin/develop` points to commit `H`.

(By the way, commits up through `E` are now on *both* branches.  This is something that is peculiar to Git: most version control systems say that a commit is on *one* branch, but in Git, any commit can be on *many* branches.  A commit is found by starting with a branch name, going to its last commit, and then working backwards.  Commit `E` is the last commit of `master`, but is also found by going to `H`—the last commit of `develop`—and then working backwards three steps, so `E` is on both branches.  All commits before `E` are on both branches, too.)

If you now run `git checkout develop`, your Git *creates* a new `develop` name.  Your Git tries to check out the existing `develop`, sees that there isn't one, and would error-out—but wait, there's `origin/develop`!  Your Git now bets that what you wanted was to *create* `develop` using the same commit identified by `origin/develop`.  So your Git does that, and then attaches your `HEAD` to that name:

```
...--o--E   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          F--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
```

Your Git will extract all the files from the snapshot for commit `H` into a workspace, which Git calls your *work-tree*.  (I'm leaving out all the stuff about Git's *index*, which is really important.)

You can now make new commits, if you like, in the usual way.  (This involves Git's index, which is one reason it's so important.)  Let's say you do—that you make one new commit, which we'll call `I`.

The parent of new ordinary commit `I` will be commit `H`: `I` will point back to `H`.  Git will write `I`'s actual hash ID into the name `develop`, since `HEAD` is attached to `develop`.  The result looks like this:

```
...--o--E   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          F--G--H   <-- origin/develop
                 \
                  I   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

If you add a new commit that we'll call `J`, Git keeps adding as usual:

```
...--o--E   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          F--G--H   <-- origin/develop
                 \
                  I--J   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

At this point, you might wonder if, or notice that, someone has done some work and sent new commits to the other Git over at `origin`.  You don't have them yet, but you can now have your Git call up their Git and *get* them:

```
git fetch origin
```

Your Git calls up their Git (using the URL saved in the name `origin`), asks them about their branch names and last commits, finds that they have their `develop` pointing to a new commit with a hash ID your Git has never heard of, and asks them for their new commits.  They say *I have some commit ______* (some big ugly hash ID): we'll call that `L`.  They say *The parent of `L` is _____* (some big ugly hash ID): we'll call that `K`.  They say *The parent of `K` is `H`*, and hey, we already have commit `H`.  So your Git has their Git send over commits `K` and `L` (only), which your Git puts in your repository.

Then, your Git updates your `origin/develop` to remember that *their* `develop` points to commit `L`.  So you now have:

```
...--o--E   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          F--G--H--K--L   <-- origin/develop
                 \
                  I--J   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

in your repository.  Note that your own `develop` is **not affected**.  A `git fetch` operation only updates your *remote-tracking names*.  It does not affect any of your *branch names*, because your branch names are *yours*, not theirs.

#### Handling divergence with `git merge`

Now that you have this:

```
          I--J   <-- develop (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- origin/develop
```

situation, you have to figure out what to *do* about this divergence.  You need to combine your work—your two commits `I-J`—with theirs, their `K-L`.  You can use `git merge` or `git rebase` to do this, and these are the two most common things to want to do.

If you want to run `git merge`, you can do that now:

```
git merge origin/develop
```

This combines work and, if it can, makes a new *merge commit* on its own:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- develop (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- origin/develop
```

The new commit goes on your branch, just like any other new commit.  It has a snapshot, just like any other new commit.  (The snapshot is the one Git made by figuring out what you did to `H`, and what they did to `H`, and combining those and doing that to the snapshot from `H`.)  It has an author and committer metadata, just like any other commit.  The author and committer, and the date-and-time-stamps, are *you:* you made this merge commit.  It has a log message, just like any ordinary commit.  There's a default, low-quality message here; you can put in a better one, but in practice nobody seems to bother:

```
merge branch 'origin/develop' into develop
```

The only thing that is special about this new merge commit `M` is that it has not one but *two* parents.  One parent is your previous commit `J`.  That's the *first* parent too, which is important later (but not really right now).  The *second* parent is the commit your `origin/develop` names, i.e., commit `L`.

#### Merge doesn't always have to merge

Sometimes you don't have a divergence.  For instance, suppose you *didn't* make any new commits—that you started with:

```
...--o--E   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          F--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
```

and stuck with that.  Then your ran `git fetch` and they'd made two new commits, which we'll call `I-J` as before:

```
...--o--E   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          F--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD)
                 \
                  I--J   <-- origin/develop
```

You can now run `git merge origin/develop` as before.  Your Git will notice that the base for this merge, commit `H`, is also the tip of your `develop`.  That is, if we did a real merge, we'd combine what *we* did, `H`-vs-`H` (nothing), with what *they* did, `H`-vs-`J`.  The result would obviously match `J`: do nothing, then do something, results in whatever the "do something" did.

Your Git will, by default, *not* do anything to merge "nothing" with "something".  It will, instead, just check out commit `J` directly *and* slide your name `develop` forward.  Git calls this a *fast-forward merge*, but there's no actual merging.  The result looks like this:

```
...--o--E   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          F--G--H
                 \
                  I--J   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
```

which we can draw more simply as:

```
...--o--E   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          F--G--H--I--J   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
```

We're back to having your `develop` and your `origin/develop` point to *the same* commit, in this case, commit `J`.

#### The bottom line about merging

The end result here is this: `git merge` can do a *fast-forward*, which isn't really a merge, and doesn't make a new commit.  Or, it can do a *true merge*, which is really a merge, and *does* make a new commit.

Git can only do a fast-forward merge under two conditions:

- First, your *current* commit must match the *merge base* that `git merge` finds on its own.  That's the case when you haven't made any commits yourself.
- Second, you must *tell* `git merge` that this is allowed or required.  But "allowed" is the default.  Using `git merge --ff-only` tells Git that it's *required*, and using `git merge --no-ff` tells Git that it's *forbidden*.  The default is: allowed; do it if possible.

If a fast-forward is possible and allowed-or-required, that's what Git does.  Otherwise Git needs to due a real merge.  If that's forbidden—if a fast-forward is required instead—the `git merge` command errors out and does nothing.  Only when a real merge is both allowed and necessary, or is forced by `--no-ff`, do we get the a real merge.

#### Notes on `git pull`

The `git pull` command just does runs two Git commands for you, as a sort of convenience wrapper:

1. First, it runs `git fetch`.  This works the way `git fetch` always works.
2. Second, it runs `git merge` (or if you tell it to, `git rebase` instead).

Assuming you use the default `git merge`, this second Git command takes the fetched updates and merges them, either fast-forward or real.  If it does a fast-forward, it doesn't make any new commit.  If it goes for a real merge, and the merge succeeds, it *does* make a new commit.

There's one special change here, vs just doing `git fetch && git merge` yourself.  The low-quality default merge message for a `git merge` you do yourself is:

```
merge branch 'origin/develop' into develop
```

The low-quality default merge message that `git pull` supplies is:

```
merge branch 'develop' of <url> into develop
```

where the *`url`* part comes from the URL saved under the name `origin`.

#### Git's merge doesn't always succeed on its own

A `git merge` that has to do a real merge can have *merge conflicts*.  This answer is already too long, so I won't go into any detail here, but the merge conflicts are represented by an unusual state in Git's index.  Your job at this point becomes to resolve the conflicts, and put the correct resolutions into Git's index.  This is another reason knowing a lot about Git's index is important.

The final merge, conflicted or not, will have a snapshot of all of your files.  If Git makes the merge on its own, *Git* made the snapshot.  If there are merge conflicts, *you* control the final snapshot yourself.

Comment: Thank you, torek